# How to use Nested components in angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm looking for a solution which will help me in developing a nested component structure.

For example:

```
<workBook>
    <workSheet [id]="1" [name]="'a'" [data]="111"></workSheet>
    <workSheet [id]="2" [name]="'b'" [data]="222"></workSheet>
    <workSheet [id]="3" [name]="'c'" [data]="333"></workSheet>
</workBook>
```

Currently, I'm using `@contentChild` in workbook component and can access the worksheet's properties in the workbook.

The worksheet template content is :

```
<div> {{id}} -- {{name}} -- {{data}} </div>
```

How to make this content in the application visible?
Only the content of the workbook is currently visible.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Remove brackets `<workSheet id="1" name="'a'" data="111"></workSheet>` and check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your workBook looks something like this:

```
<div>WorkBook Title</div>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Since you have multiple workSheet-elements inside your workBook, you need to use ContentChildren in the WorkBookComponent if you want to access the children from the parent component that contains both workBook and workSheet:

```
  @ContentChildren(ChildDirective) contentChildren: QueryList<ChildDirective>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // now you can access the contentChildren-array.
  }
```

If you don't need to access them in the parent-component, just put the workSheet in the template of workBook and use ViewChildren() instead of ContentChildren()